# Why isn't speech recognition working in my webapp? Is it because I'm autoplaying a video?

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, speech-recognition

I have a web form that just gets user info and is then appended to the next page. I want to "automate" the form by having a user's microphone grab their verbalized data and append it to the form. Everything works except the actual speech recognition...in fact, I'm not even being asked to allow my microphone access which makes me think that my video is interfering with it. I think it could also be stemming from my javascript for loop, that is supposed to have three sets of speech recognition that is appended to their respective inputs. Do I need to use websockets for it?

Index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<!---------Therapist Section--------->
    <section id="therapist">
        <div class="container" id="therapist_container">
            <script>
              function getLocalStream() {
                  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: false, audio: true}).then( stream => {
                      window.localStream = stream;
                      window.localAudio.srcObject = stream;
                      window.localAudio.autoplay = true;
                  }).catch( err => {
                      console.log("u got an error:" + err)
                  });
              }

              getLocalStream();
            </script>
            <div id="button">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="therapist-button" onclick="SpeechRecog" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Talk with Delphi</button>
            </div>
            
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="vid1Title" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <video width="100%" id="video1">
                      <source src="./static/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
                    <form action="/care" id="careid" name="care" method="POST">
                      <input type="text" id="1" name="name" placeholder="what's your name?">
                      <input type="text" id="2" name="location" placeholder="Where are you?">
                      <input type="text" id="3" name="state" placeholder="how can I help?">
                      <input id="buttonInput" class="btn btn-success form-control" type="submit" value="Send">
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <script>
              $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                $('#video1')[0].play();
              })
              $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                $('#video1')[0].pause();
              })

              video = document.getElementById('video1');
              video.addEventListener('ended',function(){       
                window.location.pathname = '/care';
                document.care.submit();
              })

              
              function SpeechRecog() {u
                    var action = document.getElementById("careid");
                    var SpeechRecognition = webkitSpeechRecognition();
                    var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
                
                    
                    for (let i=0; i < 3; i++){
                      recognition.onspeechend = function() {
                        var output = document.getElementById(i);
                        recognition.onresult = function(event) {
                          var transcript = event.results[0][0].transcript;
                          var confidence = event.results[0][0].confidence;
                          output.value=transcript;
                        };  
                      }
                      recognition.stop();
                    }                    
                  
                    // start recognition
                    recognition.start();
              }
            </script>
        </div>
    </section>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: any message in the brower *developer* console - I also wonder if microphone access requires a secure web page - does your code work WITHOUT the video, that's the first thing I would've tested if I thought it was the issue, like you suggested

Comment: Good question! I've tried that and it doesn't change a thing. Could it be because I'm running it through flask locally and not on a production server?

Comment: So, nothing to do with video - is the production server HTTPS? Also, my first question - are there any errors in the browser *developer* tools console - the first place to go when debugging *browser* issues

Comment: My bad, no errors! I'm running it locally, so the production server shouldn't matter right? Not really sure!

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood - I thought any access to microphones etc only work in a "secure page" - i.e. `https` ... some browsers do consider "localhost" to be secure - not sure Chrome or Edge-Chrome or Safari do so (the only browsers that have the API you are using) - but then, you'd get an error (or some sort of warning) in the console if that was the case I guess - I don't know, sometimes Chrome is too quiet in the console for my liking

Comment: Ah ha! I restarted everything and just found an error. It says: OSError: [Errno 41] Protocol wrong type for socket

Comment: I don't know anything about websockets, is there where I need to be looking?